# "[node:flag-vote-count]" displays the token name, not the number

Tags: tokens, flags

I have a problem in the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module with the *[node:flag-vote-count]* token. I googled for a solution, but I couldn't find one.

On my content page, the Flag module displays the token name (i.e. *[node:flag-vote-count]*) on the node creation preview page, instead of a number.

I am putting the token on the Flag -> Edit -> "Flag link text" field. Meaning inside the flag itself. *[node:title]* is working perfectly fine there.

Someone can help me here?

Comment: Where are you putting the token exactly? If it's in the content body do you have a filter module installed that converts tokens?

Comment: I am putting the token on the Flag -> Edit -> "Flag link text" field. Meaning inside the flag itself.
The [node:title] token is working perfectly fine there.
I edit my question and add this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

OK , so I solve it.

The [node:flag-vote-count] is really not working.
But you can look for another count token for the flag you created, under the TOKEN REPLACEMENT -> nodes.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It's works fine:

If i have name variable of flag: **'bookmarks'**

I most replace this **[node:flag-vote-count]** to this **[node:flag-bookmarks-count]**

If your name variable for example like this: **'bookmarks_this'**,

you need write toke like so: **[node:flag-bookmarks-this-count]**

Answer (score 0):

When a single token is not replace, it means that none of the modules implementing tags gave a value for the token you are using.

Looking at [flag.tokens.inc](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/flag/tree/flag.tokens.inc), which contains the code for listing and generating the Flag module tokens, I notice it is using the following code to generate the token you are trying to use.

```
  // We only provide tokens on entity types if we have token module's helper
  // methods available.
  if (isset($data[$type]) && module_exists('token')) {
    $entity_type = token_get_entity_mapping('token', $type);
    if ($entity_type && in_array($entity_type, flag_get_types())) {
      $flags = flag_get_flags($entity_type);
      $object = $data[$type];
      foreach ($flags as $flag) {
        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
          $flag_count_token = 'flag-' . str_replace('_', '-', $flag->name) . '-count';
          $flag_link_token = 'flag-' . str_replace('_', '-', $flag->name) . '-link';
          if ($name == $flag_count_token) {
            $replacements[$original] = $flag->get_count($flag->get_entity_id($object));
          }
          elseif ($name == $flag_link_token) {
            $replacements[$original] = flag_create_link($flag->name, $flag->get_entity_id($object));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

To see that token, you need to have the Token module installed, since [flag.info](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/flag/tree/flag.info) doesn't require it as dependency, if not for executing the tests. You also need to use the correct flag name, which means that if you are using *[node:flag-vote-count]*, but the flag name is bookmarks, you are using the wrong token name, which should instead be *[node:flag-bookmarks-count]*.

I didn't test it, but probably you would get back the token name if the node doesn't have any value for that flag.